# How to fix first click on 'set' is null, second click only get the date

Tags: java, android, validation, date

The system works fine. But whenever this function is called and pops out dialog box, whether I selected the date on not at the first time, the date is null. It only gets the date after I set it again.

This is the error 'E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null'

```
else if(v==editTextDate){

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    day = day + 1;
    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(MakeResv.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth, mDateSetListener, year, month, day);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.show();

    mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){
        //GET CURRENT DATE
        String currentdate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        //SPLIT
        String[] items1 = currentdate.split("/");
        String dateOnly=items1[0];
        String monthOnly=items1[1];
        String yearOnly=items1[2];
        //convert splited string to integer
        int dateOnlyInt = Integer.parseInt(dateOnly);
        int monthOnlyInt = Integer.parseInt(monthOnly);
        int yearOnlyInt = Integer.parseInt(yearOnly);

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            month = month +1;
            Log.d("myTag", "888 "+dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year );
            String date = dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year;
            //editTextDate.setText(date);


            if (year<yearOnlyInt||month<monthOnlyInt||dayOfMonth<=dateOnlyInt){
                //editTextDate.setError("Invalid year");

                Toast.makeText(MakeResv.this,"Invalid date",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                editTextDate.getText().clear();
                editTextDate.setHint("Choose a date");
                return;
            }else{
                editTextDate.setText(date);
            }
        }

    };


}
```

I expected to get the date value first time after I 'Set' it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using EditText and this causes the problem.

use TextView on place of EditText.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it,  but same result. First time dialog box pops up, select and set the date or not, the date remains null. Second time only works.